# Declaring multiple variables in a for loop python

Tags: python, pygame

I currently have this code written to declare 10 variables in python:

```
oneScore = textFont.render('1.   ' + str(sortedList[0][0]) + '   ' + str(sortedList[0][1]), True, white)
twoScore = textFont.render('2.   ' + str(sortedList[1][0]) + '   ' + str(sortedList[1][1]), True, white)
threeScore = textFont.render('3.   ' + str(sortedList[2][0]) + '   ' + str(sortedList[2][1]), True, white)
fourScore = textFont.render('4.   ' + str(sortedList[3][0]) + '   ' + str(sortedList[3][1]), True, white)
fiveScore = textFont.render('5.   ' + str(sortedList[4][0]) + '   ' + str(sortedList[4][1]), True, white)
sixScore = textFont.render('6.   ' + str(sortedList[5][0]) + '   ' + str(sortedList[5][1]), True, white)
sevenScore = textFont.render('7.   ' + str(sortedList[6][0]) + '   ' + str(sortedList[6][1]), True, white)
eightScore = textFont.render('8.   ' + str(sortedList[7][0]) + '   ' + str(sortedList[7][1]), True, white)
nineScore = textFont.render('9.   ' + str(sortedList[8][0]) + '   ' + str(sortedList[8][1]), True, white)
tenScore = textFont.render('10.   ' + str(sortedList[9][0]) + '   ' + str(sortedList[9][1]), True, white)
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Do they need to be in the form of variables? Could you possibly put them in a dictionary? EDIT: or any other sequence type

Comment: This is a pet peeve of mine, but *Python does not have variable declarations*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with named variables. That's what lists are for

```
score[i] = textFont.render('1.   ' + str(sortedList[i][0]) + '   ' + str(sortedList[i][1]), True, white)
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that, thanks.